# MongoDB aggregation by array field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose my collection contains documents like:

> {"email": "jim@abc.com",    "fb" : {      "name" : {
>                   "full" : "Jim Bent"} },   "apps": ["com.abc.1", "com.abc.2"]}
>
> {"email": "john@abc.com",    "fb" : {      "name" : {
>                   "full" : "John Smith"}},   "apps": ["com.abc.1", "com.abc.3" ]}

I want to write a query and export it out via a csv file that outputs the emails, fb.name.full grouping by the "apps" array fields in this entire collection.
That is: for "com.abc.1", it outputs Jim Bent with his email and John Smith and email. 
For "com.abc.2", it will output only Jim Bent, whilst for "com.abc.3", it will output only John Smith.

I have researched a bit, but mongoexport doesn't allow complex queries, and I am not able to write an $unwind function either. So i am hitting a wall.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any drivers?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Javascript and the mongo shell by creating a file (eg: `myquery.js`) with the following code:

```
printjson(
  db.collection.aggregate([
   {$unwind: '$apps'},
   {$group: { _id: '$apps', info: { '$push': { email: '$email', name: '$fb.name.full'}}}},
   {$project: {app: '$_id', info: 1, '_id': 0}}
  ]))
```

then you can perform the query from the command line as:

```
mongo database myquery.js
```

Comment: Is there anyway it can be exported to a csv file? The result of the query above is more than the max document size of 16MB, and cannot be executed.

Comment: if this operation exceeds 16MB I don't think you can do much, and a CSV export will make no difference. See here for a good explanation on that limit http://stackoverflow.com/a/14580774/687142 . One possible workaround would be to split your query to multiple ones with limited scopes, and then reconstruct the results in application space.