# how to convert aggregate to mapReduce using Laravel MongoDB by jenssegers

Tags: mongodb, laravel

Right now, I have the below code in my laravel app. I'm running into this error: `mongo1:27017: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)`. I read that I should use `mapReduce` instead of `aggregate` to avoid this issue but am unsure how to translate the below to `mapReduce` using Laravel MongoDB by jenssegers.

Here is my code using aggregate:

```
$email_duplicates = User::raw(function ($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate(
        [
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => [
                        'email' => '$email',
                    ],
                    'uniqueIds' => [
                        '$addToSet' => '$_id',
                    ],
                    'count' => [
                        '$sum' => 1,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                '$match' => [
                    'count' => [
                        '$gt' => 1,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'allowDiskUse' => true,
        ]
    );
});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255816/what-can-be-done-with-mongo-aggregation-performance-of-mongo-aggregation

Comment: Thanks, I have read that as well! That is why I would like to use `mapReduce` instead of `aggregate` so I don't run into that error. Anyone know how I can change this to `mapReduce` so it'll do the same thing?